# How to install Chrome on Kali linux arm64

Tags: google-chrome, kali-linux, microsoft-edge

The architecture of my Kali is arm64. How to should I install chrome or even edge browser on this system? Because both chrome and edge only support amd64.
Please help.

Comment: Google based on my research doesn’t publish ARM64 Chrome builds, and as far as I can tell Edge ARM64 builds only exist for Windows on ARM. The good news Chromium ARM64 builds do exist

Comment: Why did you install Kali in the first place?  It was designed to be a stripped down Linux for penetration testing and security auditing.  The fact that you are trying to install user packages into it tells me that you missed the point.  Kali is not intended to be a user OS.  By the time you tweak it back into being one, you are looking at the Debian that it came from.

Comment: I installed kali for pentesting and I am installing chrome for learning beef.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer is as given in the comments. Chromium can be installed in place of chrome.